# Call a Javascript in my <head> after sharing.. + Few questions

Tags: javascript, html

I've been playing around with a script, and really want it to work, however I'm pretty clueless, and would really appreciate some help here.

What this script does is: You send a person to the page, the video on the page plays for 7 seconds, then stops, and asks the viewer to share the page. 
After the page has been shared, I want to content lock it (using the javascript that is in the head section) Problem is, how do I do that? And how do I redirect the viewer after the content locker has been completed?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0041)http://ultimatescript.net84.net/show.html -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.imgur.com/5q3B3Y4.jpg"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Share to View</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yotefiles.com/script_include.php?id=526879"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js">
</script>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#shareonfacebook').click(function (e) {
  //          alert('hello9');
//  $(".closeBtn").show();
            e.preventDefault();
            FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'Boy Falls Into Gorilla Cage. What Happens Next... Will SHOCK you!',
                    link: 'http://crazyvideotoday.blogspot.com/ncr',
                    caption: 'Click Here To Watch This Horrific Video!',
                    description: '4 Year Old Boy Attacked By Gorilla!',
                    message: 'Hello'},
                function(response){
      if(response && response.post_id) {
// self.location.href = 'http://www.thomaspynchon.com/inherent-vice.html'
$(".closeBtn").show();
}
    else {
    // self.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/'
    //   $(".closeBtn").show();

      } 
                });
        });
  });
</script>
        <style type="text/css"><!--
body, p, td {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana;

}

html { 
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/YskVi6d.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#content {
    border: 0px groove silver;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: black
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: url('')
}

        .auto-style1 {
            margin-top: 44px;
            margin-bottom: 21px;
        }

    .hidden { visibility: hidden; }
    .unhidden { visibility: visible; } 
    #amitDiv {
    display:none;position: absolute;
top: 76px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: black;
width: 543px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: -30px;
padding:91px 10px 10px 10px;
height: 250px;
    }

    .closeBtn{
    display:none;
    background-color: red;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
padding: 3px 8px;
position: relative;
top: 80px;
right: 272px;
cursor: pointer;
    }
    #shareonfacebook{
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/dZOwP47.png);
    width: 300px;
    height: 73px;
    text-indent: -1000px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
        --></style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0; ">
    <div id="content" style="width: 555px; height: 395px;" class="auto-style1">
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="amitDiv" ><button id="shareonfacebook" ></button>

<script>
FB.init({
appId : '1508997766063227'
});
</script>

<div class='closeBtn' onclick="startGateway('NjY3NDY5');">Close<div>

</div>
    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
      playerVars: {
         'showinfo': 0,    
             'autohide': 1,   
             'modestbranding': 0,  
          },
          height: '310',
          width: '560',
          wmode:'opaque',
          videoId: 'H59vrp-84QU',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 7000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();

      $("#amitDiv").slideDown(1000);
      }
function closewhiteDiv() {
       $("#amitDiv").slideUp(1000);
}  
      </script>     
<!-- End content -->
</div>  
    </body></html>
```

[Here is my test site, so you know what I'm trying to do..](http://crazyvideotoday.blogspot.com/ncr)

I really hope someone can help me out!!! Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to content lock it"?

Comment: Content lock it with a widget (CPA). This is the javascript I want to execute once the page has been shared: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://yotefiles.com/script_include.php?id=526879"></script>

Comment: Sounds like DRM to me, I am out.